# How to connect RIDGID LM-400 distance meter with iOS via Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, gamekit

I am in a position to integrate some popular `BLE distance meters` to the business logic where I am working with. I have already succeeded integrating some leading models with the help of `iOS CoreBluetooth.framework`. But connecting `RIDGID LM-400` gives me real headache.

1. I have already tried a lot with BLE (`CoreBluetooth.framework`) but
   no response.
2. I found some tutorials for Bluetooth Connectivity with `GameKit` using
   `GKPeerPickerController`, `GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate`, `GKSession`,
   and `GKSessionDelegate`, but no positive result.

**Questions:**

1. What are the other `possibilities` to connect a bluetooth device with iOS other than `CoreBluetooth` and `GameKit`? I have already tried the [BluetoothManager](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) `private framework` but then my App will be rejected, therefore it is useless.
2. I have downloaded the [RIDGID Sketch](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/ridgid-sketch/id778548899?mt=8) App from `App Store` and installed and I have tried to connect the device. As soon as I have powered on the device I got a `message` exactly shown in the screenshot. With the help of this tip can anyone guess which way uses the App to get connected with the device? How does the Sketch App exactly knows that it has to be connected with the device?

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: My guess is that this device isn't a BLE device and is connecting via the external accessory framework under the MFi program

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do you have any additional resources or web links for that? any example?